# Can I use my Magic Jar to move over into my matured Clone early?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Let's say I have a matured Clone and a Magic Jar. Can I use the Magic Jar to pop over into the Clone whenever I want?

Comment: When you say "early," do you mean "before the clone has matured, or "before I have died" or what?

Comment: No, I specified that the clone had already matured. By 'early' I mean 'before I have died'.  Basically using the Magic Jar effect instead of letting the Clone trigger upon death.

Answer (score 4):

### That depends on what is meant by "inert"

Magic jar permits you to attempt to possess (PHB p. 257):

> any humanoid within 100 feet of you that you can see

There clone is described as "inert" before your soul occupies it. This has multiple possible meanings, including "[lacking the power to move](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inert)" and "[not alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inert)".

If the meaning of "inert" is the former, the clone would presumably be a humanoid, and would be eligible for possession via Magic Jar (provided you could also see it). However, if it meant the latter then an argument could be made that it is not yet a humanoid, but an object (an unliving body that will become humanoid later). In that case, it may not be an eligible target for Magic Jar.

This is backed up by the descritpion of what happens to your original remains if you die and your soul transfers to a clone (as per the Clone spell, PHB p. 222 bold added):

> The original creature’s physical remains, if they still exist, **become inert** and can’t thereafter be restored to life

This might be seen to imply that not only does "inert" suggest an unliving state, it is even less alive than a typical corpse since it cannot be resurrected.

Your DM will have to make a decision. But your safest bet (and this may be the only time I've ever said this) would be to just die. That way, you'd transfer to the clone as normal, and could proceed from there.